# NGINX as proxy of Node.js

Tags: node.js, nginx, express

I'm using NODE.js behind NGINX server, this is my Nginx configuration:

```
upstream example.it {
        server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
        server_name www.example.it;

        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://example.it;
                proxy_redirect  off;
                proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

All works good, the requests are correctly sent from nginx to node BUT I saw a problem in the log file generated from Express.js.

The problem is that *ALL THE REQUESTS* are saved as done from 127.0.0.1, why?

I don't seen any remove hosts (the real ip of who made the request).

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's correct, as nginx will be the remote host. You need to specify a custom log format to log the `X-Forwarded-For` header, see the [connect logger documentation](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-logger.html).

```
app.use(express.logger(':req[X-Forwarded-For] - - [:date] ":method :url HTTP/:http-version" :status :res[content-length] ":referrer" ":user-agent"'));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this.  I found it via a Google search to solve the same problem I was having just now.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you're using Express 3.0, a better way to do this is through the `trust proxy` setting.

From the [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.set):

> `trust proxy` Enables reverse proxy support, disabled by default

In order to use it:

```
app.set('trust proxy', true);
app.use(express.logger('default'));
```

This has the added advantage of working correctly when you're using a proxy as when you're not (for example in a development environment).

Comment: You can also have different settings for loggin, one for development and one for production, like this:


    // Settings for development
    app.configure('development', function(){
      app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    });

    // Settings for production
    app.configure('production', function(){
        app.set('trust proxy', true);
        app.use(express.logger('default'));  
    });

Then change your enviroment vars like this (Linux/Unix)

    NODE_ENV=production PORT=3000 node app.js

Windows:

    SET NODE_ENV=production && SET PORT=3000 && node app.js